# Selenium WebDriver Log Out from Facebook

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Does anyone know how to click log out button? I tried using `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log out"));`

But it returned an error saying element is not found. Is it because the list is dynamically generated?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until `elementToBeClickable` it works for me as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

WebElement accountSettings = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Account Settings")));
accountSettings.click() //this will click on setting link to open menu

WebElement logOut = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Log Out")));
logOut.click() // this will click on logout link
```

Hope it helps...:)

Answer (score 0):

I assume, after click on arrow button, Log Out button appers in ur code. So to click on that log Out button, use the below portion as cssSelector:

a[data-gt*='menu_logout']>span>span._54nh

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[data-gt*='menu_logout']>span>span._54nh"));
```