# How to logout of Facebook using selenium.WebDriver and HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: java, facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium.WebDriver and HtmlUnitDriver to login to Facebook, but I can't logout.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
System.out.println("Title of the page "+ driver.getTitle());
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
username.sendKeys("xxxxx@gmail.com"); 
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
password.sendKeys("xxxxx");
WebElement Signup_button = driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton"));
Signup_button.click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.println("After login title is = " + driver.getTitle());
```

Until now it works. And The following steps cover the logout part (not working):

```
WebElement logOut = driver.findElement(By.id("userNavigationLabel"));
logOut.click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
WebElement signOut = driver.findElement(By.name("Log Out"));
logOut.click();

System.out.println("Logged Out Successfully!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
String pagetitle = driver.getTitle();
System.out.println(pagetitle);

}}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element with name: Log Out
```

Facebook Logout html code

```
<span><span class="_54nh"><form class="_w0d"
 action="https://www.facebook.com/logout.php" data-nocookies="1" 
id="show_me_how_logout_1" method="post" onsubmit="return window.Event
 &amp;&amp; Event.__inlineSubmit &amp;&amp; 
Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)"><input name="fb_dtsg" 
value="AQGzvtPjFD1W:AQFslBEMcQG9" autocomplete="off" type="hidden"><input
 autocomplete="off" name="ref" value="mb" type="hidden"><input 
autocomplete="off" name="h" value="AfeziZXPRhN6ncxD" type="hidden">
</form>Log Out</span></span>
```

I have also tried this Code by  Saurabh Gaur [Selenium WebDriver Log Out from Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524957/selenium-webdriver-log-out-from-facebook)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement accountSettings = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Account Settings")));
accountSettings.click() //this will click on setting link to open menu
WebElement logOut = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Log Out")));
logOut.click() // this will click on logout link
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.linkText: Log Out
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03'
System info: xxxxxxxxxxx java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:259)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:228)
    at HtmlDemoProgram1.main(HtmlDemoProgram1.java:53)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: No link found with text: Log Out
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver Log Out from Facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524957/selenium-webdriver-log-out-from-facebook)

Comment: What do you mean still not working?? could you share how did you tried from suggested link??

Comment: Are you sure it throws `NoSuchElementException` because  `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Log Out")));` line would throws `TimeoutException` if condition does not met? please verify it.

Comment: Updated the trace with more verbose, see updated question

Comment: FInd whether LOGOUT is in other frame.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Logout

Thread.sleep(3000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'userNavigationLabel')]")).click();

Thread.sleep(3000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='_54nh'][contains(.,'Log Out')]")).click();

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute in name(locator), please use another attribute(locator) as id="show_me_how_logout_1" or any other locator.

Comment: It's still not working, here is the modification I made ------- WebElement signOut = driver.findElement(By.id("show_me_how_logout_1"));
     signOut.click();  ----- Error oSuchElementException: Unable to locate element with ID: show_me_how_logout_1

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
WebElement logOut = driver.findElement(By.id("userNavigationLabel"));
logOut.click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
WebElement signOut = driver.findElement(By.partialLinktext("Log Out"));
signOut.click();
```

Comment: Thanks Same issue; org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: No link found with text: Log Out

Answer (score 0):

Below code may help you.... Thanks.

package open_website;

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    public class Open_website_1
    {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String expath = "D:\\Eclipse\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe";

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Eclipse\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("http:\\www.facebook.com");
    WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
    element1.sendKeys("patil_y7@yahoo.com");

    WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
    element2.sendKeys("pa$$word123");

    WebElement element3 = driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_q"));
    element3.click();

    System.out.println("Login");

    WebElement lstitem=driver.findElement(By.id("userNavigationLabel"));
    lstitem.click();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Log Out")).click();

    System.out.println("Log out");


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

public void LogOutFB()throws Exception{

```
    WebElement logOut = driver.findElement(By.id("userNavigationLabel"));
    logOut.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='_54nh'][contains(.,'Log Out')]")).click();
    System.out.println("Logged Out Successfully!");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.sleep(10000);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[aria-label='आपकीप्रोफ़ाइल']>svg>path")).click();
Thread.sleep(10000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'लॉग आउट करें')][1]")).click();
System.out.println("Loggout successfuly from Mayank fb account");
```

Comment: An explanation would be great